# Magento, new Module for custom login is not loading

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm new to Magento, I have been stuck with this problem for a while. I want to create a custom URL for VIP members to login. I'm trying to create a new login page with a new module because the login process is not same as default process. My login page is not rendering correctly.

Module download link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3l22y1w8j8_cmFkVnVZcUNzRUE

Please point out any mistakes I've made in my code please.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Module -

**app/etc/modules/Ifs_VipMember.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ifs_VipMember>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ifs_VipMember>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ifs/VipMember/Block/Index.php**

```
class Ifs_VipMember_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

}
```

**app/code/local/Ifs/VipMember/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
 class Ifs_VipMember_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

  public function IndexAction() {

  $this->loadLayout();   
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("VipLogIn"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
              "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
              "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
              "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
       ));

    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("viplogin", array(
              "label" => $this->__("VipLogIn"),
              "title" => $this->__("VipLogIn")
       ));

    $this->renderLayout(); 

  }
}
```

**app/code/local/Ifs/VipMember/etc/config.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ifs_VipMember>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ifs_VipMember>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <vipmember>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Ifs_VipMember</module>
            <frontName>vipmember</frontName>
          </args>
      </vipmember>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <vipmember>
              <file>vipmember.xml</file>
            </vipmember>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <vipmember>
        <class>Ifs_VipMember_Helper</class>
      </vipmember>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <vipmember>
        <class>Ifs_VipMember_Block</class>
      </vipmember>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ifs/VipMember/Helper/Data.php**

```
class Ifs_VipMember_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/vipmember.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
    <layout version="0.1.0">   
      <vipmember_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
          <block type="vipmember/index" name="vipmember_index" template="vipmember/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
      </vipmember_index_index>   
    </layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/vipmember/index.phtml**

```
 <!-- test -->
```

Comment: I have updated the source exactly you mentioned, Im getting a blank content. Header and footer is loading but not the content.

Comment: You have to create custom code for login in index.phtml. After that you can see the content in frontend. Also please clear the cache from admin panel.